# Should I answer to questions that go against best practices?

Tags: discussion, answers

This question originated from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44306057/visual-studio-c-sharp-auto-generated-method-adds-using-system-how-to-turn-it) on StackOverflow.

The OP was asking for something unusual: change the autogeneration tool of Visual Studio to put all the namespaces next to every referenced class, and not all together at the top of the file.

I said that's something unusual, because usually you want all the namespaces at the top in order to leave the code cleaner and more readable. And in fact a comment pointed out that fact, and it received 8 upvotes.

Now, let's speak for a general question that go against best practices and/or common sense: what's the best thing to do in this case? Should I put my effort in finding a solution for the OP, even if the path he chose is not recommanded at all? Or should I comment *"well, not a good question, don't do this, instead do this other thing!"*?

Comment: The quality of a question isn't determined by how "good" the thing being asked is. Answer high quality questions.

Comment: There are some gradients between things that are against best practices, things that you aren't sure *why* anyone would want to do, and more insidious things a la requests for SQL injection enabling "solutions".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the best course of action would be to post an answer with:

- the answer to the question as asked, and
- a further explanation of why this is not best practice, and
- the answer that conforms to that best practice.

Obviously, that could be a lot of work, so it's up to you whether you want to do that, but it would be a great answer!

Comment: Not only is this just wrong (there *are* situations where providing an answer to the question asked is very clearly harmful to any expert in the subject matter), but it doesn't even apply to the specific example asked about here.  In the specific example the question itself explains what the common approach is when explaining what they want, and can clearly see the problems that the meta OP has with it, so none of this would even be needed in that situation.  (There are also going to be plenty of situations where an alternate solution *can't* be provided with the information given.)

Comment: Ðаn has a good point: "Don't do that!" is a good answer. It might not be the answer the asker wants (and they might downvote it because of that) but sometimes "No" is the only valid answer. Just be aware that it might be negatively received and resign yourself to a little rep loss in the cause against terrible, terrible ideas.

Answer (score 5):

This is going to be a judgement call that you'll need to make based on the specific circumstances.  It's pretty uncommon to see questions about things that are unambiguously and universally wrong to do (in the rare cases where that comes up, it's generally an easy decision to make to simply not provide the direct answer at all, because you're only ever causing harm; more on this later on); more often what you come across are things that are *typically* wrong or unlikely to be suitable for whatever problem the OP actually has.

Given that, an important thing to consider is how confident are you that the author, and other future readers likely to come across the question, are actually going to be in a situation in which this possibly worrying practice is actually appropriate.  If you think there's a reasonable chance that the question author, or even a notable number of future readers of the question, are actually going to be in a situation where the solution presented is appropriate, then it's likely going to be helpful to provide one.

It's also important to consider the possible negative ramifications of the solution(s) you're providing, if they're used in an inappropriate context.  If the problem with someone using your solution when they shouldn't is less elegant code, slightly less performant code, or something else suitably minor, then providing a solution is much more likely to be acceptable.  If the problems of the solution are, or could be, major security vulnerabilities, or other very impactful but hard to notice/diagnose problems, then you should be *much* more hesitant to provide a solution.

Worth noting as well is that if you *do* decide to provide a solution in such cases, you should take care to point out the potential problems with the solutions, describe the situations where it is and is not appropriate to use it, and if you think there's a reasonable chance that the author or future readers shouldn't be using this solution, you should try to provide (or at least describe) the solution that *would* be appropriate (if possible; sometimes knowing what other solution would be appropriate would require more information than you have).

Another option to consider, particularly as the problems with the actual answer (or the likelihood of it being inappropriate) go up, you may consider avoiding providing a completely coded solution that would tempt people to copy-paste it.  By explaining what one would need to do to solve the problem, and potentially providing some of the relevant code but without enough that someone could copy-paste the whole thing, you will help limit the danger of someone copy-pasting the code without reading through your answer to see what problems the solution has and your description of when it is or is not appropriate.

As the potential problems, and likelihood problems, goes up, you'll want to move more and more towards considering not providing a solution to the problem asked *at all*, merely explaining why the solution is problematic, and providing an entirely separate solution to the underlying problem that you feel *would* be appropriate to use.  Where you choose to draw this line in the sand is going to be a judgement call.

As to the specifics of the one question that you asked about, I see no reason whatsoever to not answer it.  It's an entirely acceptable thing to do under certain circumstances, the more common solution that's typically done, but isn't always an option, is listed in the question itself, the only "harm" that would come out of using the solution presented over the alternative is that the code is a bit more verbose, but most of all the fact that the whole basis of the solution is to change the default behavior, meaning that the solution *you* want the OP to use instead is the default, and that anyone using this solution is going *out of their way* to make this change because the default behavior isn't working for them.  Given all of this, there's no need to provide any alternate solutions, or to describe the drawbacks of the answer to the question (they're apparent just by looking at it), and there's no harm at all in providing an actual solution. If you don't want to provide an answer, feel free to not, but it's certainly not problematic for someone to do so in this situation.